# What book has the main alien antagonist as a "Blue poppet"?

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi, alien-invasion

I can't remember the title or the author. Ugh! Centers around a soldier that now kills for the conquering alien race that took over Earth. They don't know much about the aliens that control them, except they are described as blue poppets. Once back on earth the main character's friends start a rebellion. Any ideas?

Thank you so much if you know this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it. Great story.

When Heaven Fell by William Barton

Read the first few pages on Amazon preview to confirm.

Great read in my opinion. Thanks to anyone who was looking!

[Amazon Listing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00768TEYW)